# x-IMU Hard-iron calibration Values too big for Register

Tags: calibration, magnetometer, drift

I am using a x-IMU from x-io Technologies.

For drift correction it uses the AHRS On-board algorithm.
Without Hard-iron calibration there is a small continuous rotation.

From Hard-iron calibration with x-IMU-GUI-v13.1 I get values like:

- x-axis hard-iron bias: 882076,942002059
- y-axis hard-iron bias: -814599,840421389
- z-axis hard-iron bias: 834205,266804569

They are automatically set to the hard-iron bias registers.
This registers have values between -16 & 15.99951.
Which leads to following register values:

- x-axis hard-iron bias: 15.99951
- y-axis hard-iron bias: -16
- z-axis hard-iron bias: 15.99951

If I rotate the IMU horizontal, I get following values on Magnetometer y-axis:
[y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Y0O.jpg)

But all values above 16 are cut off...
There is the same problem at x-axis.

So, where is the problem?
At the Hard-iron calibration or at the magnetometer register settings?
Thanks a lot for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Customer Service of x-io Technologies Limited could help me. 
I had to change my Windows regional settings such that a decimal place is represented by a '.' and not a ','.

Now the calibration dataset is valid.